# How to read a file permission and store it in a variable in C

Tags: c, linux, file-permissions

In Linux platform(Ubuntu system).
As describe in title.
I try to get a number like '0644' and store it in a variable for later use.

Comment: It would be nice to know what platform you are using

Comment: Highly OS-dependent. For UNIX: use `stat()` or `fstat()` or `lstat()`

Comment: You should probably tag this “unix” or “linux” or “posix”. There is no answer in standard C.

Comment: An `0664` permission is highly platform-independent; of course, it's not found in systems that are not based on standards.

Comment: Read: http://james.bond.edu.au/courses/inft73626/053/Labs/Code/stat.c

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to read linux file permission programmatically in C/C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8812959/how-to-read-linux-file-permission-programmatically-in-c-c)

Answer (score 1):

the [stat, fstat, lstat](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html) system calls can be used to retrieve the permission of a file.
The field `st_mode` of the stat structure contains the permission of the file specified as argument of the system call. Then a variable of type `mode_t` can be used as local storage in your application.

This is an example :

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


#define FILE_NAME "test.c"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   struct stat sb;
   mode_t file_permision; 

   if (stat(FILE_NAME, &sb) == -1) {
        perror("stat");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

   file_permision = sb.st_mode; 
   printf(" File permission : %o (octal)\n",
            (unsigned int) file_permision); 
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that `st_mode` includes file type bits too (not to mention the SUID, SGID and SVTX bits).

Comment: Yes, you are right. In fact, the output of this program, for example `100664`, shows the file type bits too.  He should use the appropriate macros to deal with an object of type mode_t.