# Evaluating permission bit of a file

Tags: c, linux, stat

In [stat.h](https://unix.superglobalmegacorp.com/Net2/newsrc/sys/stat.h.html) there are some constants/definitions like:

```
#define S_IRWXU 0000700         /* RWX mask for owner */
#define S_IRUSR 0000400         /* R for owner */
#define S_IWUSR 0000200         /* W for owner */
#define S_IXUSR 0000100         /* X for owner */
```

I know I can use the `stat` to get 'everything':

```
$ stat file.txt
  File: file.txt
  Size: 5307        Blocks: 16         IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 10302h/66306d   Inode: 13129530    Links: 1
Access: (0775/-rwxrwxr-x)  Uid: ( 1000/  ubuntu)   Gid: ( 1000/  ubuntu)
Access: 2020-09-25 21:47:31.013446496 +0000
Modify: 2020-09-25 22:34:21.527460575 +0000
Change: 2020-09-25 22:34:21.531460600 +0000
 Birth: -
```

Within C, how could I access the structure of the file to check to see if a file has other-executable permission, the equivalent of:

```
// if the file in question has executable permissions for 'other'
if (file.txt & S_IXOTH) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: "_Is there a way to evaluate a specific 'bit' in the permission_" - Like when using [Boolean expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_expression)?

Comment: @TedLyngmo yes -- from the shell, using the `S_IRWXU` symbol, such as `file & (S_IRWXU)`

Comment: "_from the shell_" - sounds more like a question for another site. What are you trying to do really? Where does the programming question come into it?

Comment: @TedLyngmo good point. In that case, let me just change it to a C question and we'll leave it at that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read linux file permission programmatically in C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8812959/how-to-read-linux-file-permission-programmatically-in-c-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`stat` is a Linux system call, not just a shell command.

[man 2 stat](https://linux.die.net/man/2/stat)

That means you can write code like this:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {

    struct stat buf;

    if (0 == stat("file.txt", &buf)) {
        if (buf.st_mode & S_IXOTH) {
            /* do what you wanted */
        }
    } else {
        /* handle error accessing the file here **/
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks so much. One probably stupid question, but why use the `man 2` page instead of just the `man` page?

Comment: @carl.hiass number 2 is the section of the manual that lists system calls. Without it, the manual will default to section one that lists shell commands, and since there is a shell command with the same name as the system call you will get the wrong page.

Comment: @carl.hiass It's sections. in the _man_ library. You can use `man -k word` to freesearch. It's not a good seach engine but ... still, for everyday use, pretty ok.